# why not only one datasheet for STM microcontrollers

Tags: embedded, stm32f4, datasheet

I know it's not a coding question , but I am struggling with something around my head for a little bit, for example stm32f446re : why it doesn't have only one datasheet , why so many datasheet for only one microcontroller , also my question is : how could I get all different possible datasheets for a specific microcontroller like stm32f446r4 Nucleo because I searched a lot but my instructor told me that there is about 6 different datasheets for stm32f446re , but what I could find is only 2 datasheets ?

Comment: You are right, this is off-topic. Anyway, these data sheets might serve different purposes. Did you look into them? Are they all really called "data sheet"? A programmer's manual will not need electrical data, and vice versa.

Comment: that helped a lot , I really didn't know that they are called programmer's manual, but what is the difference between "data sheet" & "reference manual" ? , I don't get it. and when to use datasheet not reference manual  ?

Comment: Look into the tables of contents, the chapters' titles tell you what is in them. And the question is not "when to use what?" but rather "I need to know xxx, where do I find it?" And again, a table of contents is most helpful. -- But this is all common sense. If you don't know when to use a document, you most probably don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, documentation for microcontrollers goes like this:

- Data sheet = information for the *hardware* designers.
- Reference/User's Manual = information for the *software* designers.
- A separate *core* manual regarding the CPU Instruction Set Architecture (ISA) and assembler language, also for software designers.
- Application notes = additional information about either hw or sw.
- Errata. List of known hardware bugs. Always skim through it!

Please note that "Nucleo" etc isn't a microcontroller but a specific evaluation board. It will have additional information about that specific board.